# AS3 - Move Array objects relative to angle

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, math, actionscript, angle

I am creating a game where i need to move ships at a set speed towards the angle they are facing. I have used this code to move singular ships elsewhere in the game but i assume having them in an array has complicated things.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var ship1 = this.addChild(new Ship());
var ship2 = this.addChild(new Ship());
var ship3 = this.addChild(new Ship());
var ship4 = this.addChild(new Ship());

var shipSpeed1 = 10;

var shipArray: Array = [];

shipArray.push(ship1, ship2, ship3, ship4);

for (var i: int = 0; i < shipArray.length; i++) { 
var randomX: Number = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
var randomY: Number = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;

shipArray[i].x = randomX;
shipArray[i].y = randomY;

shipArray[i].rotation = 90;

shipArray[i].x += Math.sin(shipArray[i].rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * shipSpeed1;
shipArray[i].y -= Math.cos(shipArray[i].rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * shipSpeed1;

}
```

I've also included this within the same function, but i cant get this to work either. Once again i have had this working

```
if (shipArray[i].x < 0) { //This allows the boat to leave the scene and 
enter on the other side.
    shipArray[i].x = 750;
}
if (shipArray[i].x > 750) {
    shipArray[i].x = 0;
}
if (shipArray[i].y < 0) {
    shipArray[i].y = 600;
}
if (shipArray[i].y > 600) {
    shipArray[i].y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you used to move the singular ship.  Right now,  your code isn't moving anything beyond the initial placement.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis var ship = evt.currentTarget; 
 ship.x += Math.sin(ship.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * randomSpeed(4, 15); //Controlling the ship using my random number
 ship.y -= Math.cos(ship.rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * randomSpeed(4, 15); Its the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to separate your code into a **spawn / initialization** phase and an **update** phase.

Something like the following:

```
var shipArray: Array = [];

//spawn and set initial values (first phase)
//spawn 4 new ships
var i:int;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    //instantiate the new ship
    var ship:Ship = new Ship();
    //add it to the array
    shipArray.push(ship);

    //set it's initial x/y value
    ship.x = Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - ship.width);
    ship.y = Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - ship.height);

    //set it's initial rotation
    ship.rotation = Math.round(Math.random() * 360);

    //set the ships speed (dynamic property)
    ship.speed = 10;

    //add the new ship to the display
    addChild(ship);
}

//NEXT, add an enter frame listener that runs an update function every frame tick of the application
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameUpdate);

function gameUpdate(e:Event):void {
    //loop through each ship in the array
    for (var i: int = 0; i < shipArray.length; i++) { 
        //move it the direction it's rotated, the amount of it's speed property
        shipArray[i].x += Math.sin(shipArray[i].rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * shipArray[i].speed;
        shipArray[i].y -= Math.cos(shipArray[i].rotation * (Math.PI / 180)) * shipArray[i].speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the new issue?  The ships leave the screen?